# Laravel - Automatically load Auth::user() relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I was wondering if it's possible somehow to automatically load all `Auth::user()` relationships.

`Auth::user()` returns an instance of my `App\Models\Auth\Usuario.php`, and inside `Usuario.php` class I have some relationships with another models.

The way I'm doing it now manually loads the relations with `$user->load('relation')` but I need to do it in every request.

I was thinking to do something like this in my base Controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $this->relation = $user->load('relation');
}
```

But It's not exactly what I'm looking for.

There is another/best way to load all the `Auth::user()` class relationships? Like middleware or something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `$with` property on your model to declare relationships that should always be eager loaded.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

> Sometimes you might want to always load some relationships when
> retrieving a model. To accomplish this, you may define a $with
> property on the model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    /**
     * The relationships that should always be loaded.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = ['author'];

    /**
     * Get the author that wrote the book.
     */
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Author');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a view shared variable set in a middleware, so here is a example

1. the route:

`Route::prefix('accounts')->middleware(['auth', 'profile'])`

2. the middleware (profile) :

`view()->share('currentUser', Auth::user()>setRelations(['profile']));`

3. in any view:

`$currentUser->profile->description`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are manually loading relations, this should be done within your model?

Anyway to answer your question, i use a helpers.php which I add to composer autoload:-

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ]
```

within this helpers file you could decalare custom global methods:-

```
function current_user()
{
    return auth()->user();
}
```